# Use one toggle button to close one of two opened navbars

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have one navbar but with two toggle parts - one is menu, second is pictures with cities.

I have two buttons which toggles each of the these dropdown navbars. 
But I want to have one button which will close whichever navbar is opened.

I have added separate classes to navbars - one is .cities and the second is .menu.
Both have also classes ,,navbar-collapsed collapsed"
When I open one navbar .cities, I cannot close it with the same button as I close .menu. It just toggles also the .menu and it overrides .cities so I have two navbars opened I can then open and close only .menu with this button.

I tried changing - Data-toggle, data-target with onclick events, but nothing seems to work.

To sum up = two buttons to open two navbars (works) but one which will close whichever is opened now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this - anywhere I click outside of that navbar it will collapse. I used the same principle with some modification and I added this inside of a function linked ,,close button" so either user click anywhere on the page or directly on the close button and it will close both.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).click(function(e) {
     if (!$(e.target).is('a')) {
         $('.cities').collapse('hide');
        $('.menu').collapse('hide');
        $('#navbars').attr('data-target','.menu');        
    }
 });
 </script>
```